# What is escalate in openerp 7 and where to define the tree structure or department hierarchy for that?

Tags: odoo

I know that when we receive a task we can escalate (transfer) the job to the higher authority and this chain action will be possible until the job reaches the top level. But i am not very clear how this works in openerp 7. Please help me out with some links and example if possible.

Comment: On which context, you are talking about ? You need to know this feature on which object like Sales Team -- Lead, Issue -- Project ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Sales Team --> Leads, then In Sales Team, You need to select it's Parent Team from Sales team form view. After selecting it's parent team, from Lead form view, You will be able to escalate that lead and it will be assigned to it's parent team whatever you will select.

If you are talking about Issue --> Project, then In Project, You need to set Project Escalation field of the current project. After setting it's escalation, from Issue, You can also escalate it and it will be associated with that Escalation Project whatever you will select.